# How to get default configuration properties in MapR

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, mapr

I'm trying to find the default properties from the **MapR Hadoop**. From the [HPE](https://docs.datafabric.hpe.com/60/ReferenceGuide/ConfigurationFiles.html) website (MapR is now owned by the HPE) got to know the configuration files path. But these files show only some specific properties, not all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can run the following command

`hadoop conf-details`

The command displays the various options to get default and modified properties.

The output of the command is attached in the image below[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands to see all default MapR and Hadoop properties

1. "maprcli config load -json"
2. "hadoop conf"

Comment: ```hadoop conf-details``` is the extended command for the ```hadoop conf```